# library not found for -lidn

Tags: iphone, xcode

I was making some changes in the Build Properties of my project, just to set up the use of libxml2 library. I finally did it, but when i come back to compile my app, this error showed up:

library not found for -lidn

I am using XMPPFramework in my project, and libdn is needed. It seems that can't find the library. Any advise?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

If you install XMPPFramework via CocoaPods

1. select **Build Settings**
2. search **Library Search Paths**
3. add **"$(PODS_ROOT)/XMPPFramework/Vendor/libidn"**

Answer (score 2):

Click on `project target -> Build Settings` and search for the section named "*Library Search Paths*", click on `+` and add `XMPPFramework Path/Vendor/libidn` on `Debug` and `Release`